# Advertencia para comentarios publicados como respuesta

Tags: discusión, característica-nueva

He visto un **sinfín** de respuestas que no son más que comentarios porque el usuario no tiene Reputación suficiente.

A parte de reportar, les comento que elaboren la respuesta para que tenga un formato y una calidad suficiente o que la borren (si es que es un mero "puedes añadir el código" o otro tipo de comentario que no resuelve nada)

Ya que siempre me contestan:

> "es que no puedo comentar aún"

Últimamente estoy añadiendo a mi comentario algo así como:

> "Y si, ya sé que no tienes reputación suficiente para comentar, pero eso no quita que puedas publicar respuestas de baja calidad. **Ten paciencia**, los 50 rep llegarán".

**Ej:** (pongo imagen para quien no pueda ver respuestas borradas)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me suena de ver alguna respuesta que pone:

> Convertido a comentario por un moderador.

(Aunque no sé si los usuarios también podemos a partir de cierta rep.)

Realmente me parece muy curioso que lo hagan, es como:

> "estaba la puerta cerrada así que me colé por la ventana".

---

#### Propuesta de característica nueva:

Creo que debería haber una advertencia a aquellos que tengan menos de la reputación necesaria para comentar, que al mandar una respuesta les aclare que **las respuestas no son comentarios**.

Comment: A veces me pregunto si es buena idea que los moderadores conviertan esas "respuestas" a comentarios. Si me pongo en el lugar del que le falta reputación, yo seguiría agregando este tipo de "respuestas" contando con el hecho que alguien se encargará de convertirlo a comentario por mi.

Comment: Me perdí en la anécdota. ¿Podrías identificar la característica nueva? Con negritas o con `>` o algo así. PD. Yo también las he visto y no me parece un _sinfin_. Yo opino la cantidad es perfectamente manejable con los reportes.

Comment: @sstan hay comentarios que cuelan como respuestas pobres pero otros son obviamente comentarios y no veo el problema de convertirlos.

Comment: @toledano, hoy fueron 8 que yo viera. son muchos y hay que tenerlo en cuenta. Mi anecdota está al final pero la caracteriristica nueva que digo es la advertencia a la hora de publicar una respuesta con menos de 50 rep.

Comment: Comprendo perfectamente tu preocupación, me pregunto en qué momento la moderación dejó de ser suficiente. Creo que este es el mismo caso que el famoso letrero sobre preguntar en español que se propuso hace tiempo. En fin, @lois6b, espero que prospere tu propuesta y los usuarios sin reputación que intenten responder una pregunta vean esa advertencia.

Comment: Personalmente no comprendo la razón de permitir publicar respuestas antes que comentarios, cuando representa que las respuestas tienen mas valor. Yo lo permitiría como mucho a la vez.

Comment: @Arnau Si el concepto no está claro, podrías formularlo como pregunta acá en Meta.

Answer (score 3):

En la cola de revisiones de publicaciones de baja calidad he visto varias respuestas muy malas, pero que siguen siendo respuestas. En estos casos lo que procede es dar un voto negativo, y agregar un comentario sobre la calidad esperada de las respuestas.

Ejemplos de respuestas muy malas,

1. Respuestas demasiado cortas, el autor transcribe o hace una síntesis de la pregunta y agregan una palabra.
2. Sugiere probar o hacer algo pero no menciona razón o explicación alguna

Por el contrario, como se menciona en la pregunta, cuando a través de una respuesta se critica o solicita clarificación al autor de una pregunta o respuesta en el hilo, los moderadores diamantados pueden convertir la respuesta en un comentario<sup>1</sup>. Pero no existe un privilegio para hacer esto, que se pueda obtener por reputación, sin ser un moderador.

Mientras ellos, por lo pronto los moderadores diamantados, hacen lo que les toca, lo que estas haciendo está muy bien. Me parece que hay scripts de usuario que se puede utilizar para facilitar esta labor, si mal no recuerdo están en http://stackapps.com.

---

<sup>1</sup> : Hilos sobre convertir una respuesta en comentario

- [Should moderators be able to convert answers into comments?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35175/should-moderators-be-able-to-convert-answers-into-comments)
- [Respuesta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/117903/289691) a [Recent feature changes to Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange)

  > 2011-01-07: Moderators can now convert answers into comments.

Comment: Para mí, sugerir probar o hacer algo no es una respuesta, sino un comentario. Por tanto -para mí- esas respuestas deben eliminarse.

Comment: Cuando dices que los usuarios con privilegios por puntuación pueden convertir respuestas en comentarios... ¿Cómo se hace eso? Yo, por ejemplo, únicamente puedo reportar que la respuesta es realmente un comentario, pero la respuesta no se convierte automáticamente ¿Te refieres a eso?

Comment: No me refiero a eso. El como debe estar documentado "por ahí", es cosa de buscarlo.

Comment: @eferion: Agregué unos enlaces a publicaciones en [meta.se] sobre convertir respuestas en comentarios.

Comment: Gracias por el aviso. Les voy a echar un ojo

Comment: @eferion - Sólo los moderadores pueden convertir una respuesta en comentario. El resto de los mortales no tenemos ese superpoder.

Comment: @Mariano ya lo vi, pero el tema me sigue interesando. Quien sabe si en el futuro lo habilitan como un privilegio más

Comment: @eferion Puede ser una excelente propuesta de [meta-tag:característica-nueva], siempre y cuando esté bien pensado quiénes tienen acceso (hay [una propuesta del 2011](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70039/304899) para 20k+), para evitar abuso y maluso de usuarios menos experimentados (todos tendemos a evitar eliminar, y esto podría crear demasiados comentarios cuando correspondería eliminar)... De todas formas, hoy lo realizan los moderadores, y nunca detecté caso alguno que falte convertir o que se demore demasiado (o sea, no creo que sea un problema significativo).

Comment: @Mariano yo tampoco pienso que ahora funcione mal, pero si me parece más cómodo. Eso y poder agilizar el cierre de preguntas tipo "a ver si alguien me hace los deberes"... Que luego alguno acaba respondiendo y entonces parece que el resto somos los malos por querer cerrar la pregunta

Comment: @eferion estoy totalmente de acuerdo con eso, y confío en el criterio de la comunidad si se implementara sólo para usuarios experimentados.

Answer (score 0):

Por ahora tenemos esta advertencia:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

También existe esta respuesta a una pregunta similar.

https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1713/4

Pero, ¿Qué tal si les mostramos esta advertencia a todos los usuarios de baja reputación para cada respuesta que quieran hacer, sea suya o de otros?

Puede ser una manera de ayudarnos todos.

Comment: Esa advertencia fue diseñada para evitar que un usuario intente responder cuando debería editar la pregunta. Por eso es que dice "responder tu propia pregunta". Actualmente, un usuario nuevo recibe otras advertencias en la parte superior del cuadro de edición. (Mensaje que todos ya hemos aceptado :-))

Comment: El problema es que está el mensaje muy claro y no ser lee. La pregunta es si hay algo para hacer desde UX, o resignarnos a que es una condición del ser humano.

Comment: @Mariano eso mismo. hahah "oh no me dejan comentar. voy a buscar la primera caja de texto que vea y escribir mi comentario" xD