# Iniciativa para que un usuario de confianza pueda convertir respuestas a comentarios de usuarios nuevos

Tags: discusión, característica-nueva

Últimamente he visto mayor actividad de usuarios nuevos, los cuales desean hacer comentarios en preguntas o respuestas y al no tener la reputación necesaria publican una nueva respuesta corta que como tal no soluciona la pregunta y por tal motivo, se reporta, entra a las colas de revisión y finalmente es convertida en comentario. Por ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el mejor de los casos, la respuesta es convertida a comentario, en otros he visto hasta votos negativos.

¿Qué ocasiona esto? Algunos usuarios nuevos lo tomarán más personal que otros, entonces, puede ser que al votarles negativo algunos usuarios se sientan que reman contra la corriente quitándoles algunos de los pocos puntos que tienen, siendo imposible que lleguen mínimo a los 50 puntos de reputación para realizar comentarios.

Mi propuesta es que un usuario de confianza (4k puntos de reputación) pueda convertir la respuesta en comentario de inmediato, evitando que el usuario nuevo sea votado de forma negativa. Si algún usuario llegara a cometer alguna equivocación, entonces se puede reportar ese (anteriormente respuesta) comentario a un moderador o que simplemente entre a las colas de revisión para recuperar la respuesta.

Actualmente hay 26 usuarios de confianza, y por alguna razón muy buena se han ganado esa reputación, es normal que frecuentemente anden por el sitio.

Para esto veo principalmente 2 ventajas:

- Los usuarios nuevos no serán votados de forma negativa (en la medida de lo posible) y pueden mantener la poca reputación que han ganado hasta el momento.
- Estos reportes ya no entrarán a las colas de revisión, aminorando un poco el trabajo de los revisores.

---

Esto es solo una propuesta. Actualmente desconozco el esfuerzo que requiera realizar este *ajuste*, es posible que hasta sea mucho mayor el trabajo para intentar hacer una pequeña mejora y que finalmente no pasará nada si se sigue trabajando al día de hoy.

Comment: No lo veo mal, aunque habría que discutir como *implementarlo* ... ¿ una cola nueva (por ejemplo, `conversiones a comentarios`) ? me parece mucho trabajo. ¿ Una opción en la cola de `Publicaciones de baja calidad` y `Primeras publicaciones`, accesible solo a usuarios +4k ? Mas fácil de implementar, pero *ningunea* el posible trabajo de usuarios que editen esas *falsas respuestas* (¿Para que editar un comentario?) ¿ Y que se hace con los comentarios a esas respuestas ? ¿ Se pierden ? ...

Comment: esto se ha tratado en los comentarios de la respuesta a  [mi pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1500/advertencia-para-comentarios-publicados-como-respuesta) que es algo similar

Comment: Me gusta la idea de que deje de ser una tarea de moderadores y pase a usuarios, pero no estoy de acuerdo con la implementación propuesta. No me gustaría ver que ninguna respuesta sea eliminada por 1 solo usuario (por más que sea un caso obvio). Sí estaría más de acuerdo si se combina con las sugerencias/votos de eliminación ([como se propuso en MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70039/304899))

Comment: Conseguir comentar solo "cuesta" 50 puntos. En lugar de normalizar el uso de respuestas para comentarios, puede ser más útil recordarles que con apenas 50 puntos ya podrán hacerlo.

Comment: @Mariano el proceso sería igual que para los casos de cierre. Se *propone* para convertir en comentario, y con 5 votos se *apreba*.

Comment: @fedorqui Gran verdad eso que dices. Es la *utilidad real* que surgiría de un procedimiento así: los usuarios se acostumbran a publicar comentarios como respuestas. Seguro. Yo lo veo como una iniciativa para *descargar* de esas tareas a los moderadores, aunque el *efecto secundario* que indicas está **garantizado**.

Comment: En el caso indicado, en lugar de hacer que el usuario convierta su respuesta a comentario, lo mejor sería que se hubiese editado para convertirlo en una respuesta más completa y limpia. Así ayudan al usuario y al sitio al mismo tiempo. Y este sería el argumento principal que usaría para esta opción. Muchos usuarios prefieren penalizar las publicaciones porque "están mal" en lugar de primero proveer una ayuda a los usuarios para realmente atender esta situación. Hay casos y casos, pero principalmente he visto la falta de paciencia por sobre brindar la ayuda colaborativa.

Comment: @Luiggi: A menudo (aunque no siempre), los comentarios son para pedir a OP que aclare algún punto en su pregunta. En esos casos, no se puede mejorar el comentario para que sea una buena respuesta. Personalmente, prefiero que estos usuarios aprendan a ser pacientes tal como comentó fedorqui, y tal como se indica en el comentario que resulta de la cola de revisión en estos casos.

Comment: @sstan yo creo que sí se pueden mejorar, solo necesitan un empujón. Lo digo porque yo he sido de los usuarios que publicaban comentarios como respuesta y luego los editaba para que mejoraran. En ese lado, creo que SOen es más paciente (sí, aunque suene o se lea extraño) para eliminar respuestas, en su lugar prefieren votarte a negativo y si luego la actualizaste remueven los votos/te votan a favor.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza estoy de acuerdo contigo al decir "*Muchos usuarios prefieren penalizar las publicaciones porque "están mal" en lugar de primero proveer una ayuda a los usuarios*". Ser estrictos no es el objetivo del sitio, desafortunadamente es un comportamiento bastante frecuentre entre algunos usuarios. Talvés la razón de mi iniciativa tuvo raíz justamente en lo que me dices.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

La plataforma no permite que los usuarios de alta reputación conviertan preguntas a comentarios sin tener el diamante de moderador.  Por ahora, hay que seguir alertando a los moderadores sobre estas respuestas para que puedan ellos convertirlas en comentarios.

Se que no es lo ideal pero así está construida la cosa.